# Loading javascript function on button event

Tags: javascript, html, events, button, web

I would like to call a Javascript function once the button is displayed on screen. What I am looking for is similar to the 'onclick' attribute:

```
<input type="button" class="button-class" onclick="function(this)">
```

However, I would like the function to be called as soon as the button is displayed on screen i.e. it should be instantaneous (button creation=function call). I have already tried 'onload' but this does not seem to work. Is there a way to do this please?

Thank you

Comment: If you're creating the button using Javascript, just put the call to the function after that code.

Comment: @Barmar the button is being created using HTML as shown in the above code snippet.

Comment: @Questionnaire do you mind if i use jquery

Comment: No I dont @GerardoBLANCO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Questionnaire, you can't do what you want since an action should take place for a button (click event) to execute code.

As a good practice, load your Javascript code after the page is done loading. This is to avoid blocking the rendering of HTML code since
Javascript is synchronous.

```
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            // Code for your button function here
        }
        window.onload = init();
    </script>
 </html>
```

The code above is pretty much it.

Answer (score 3):

Put an script element invoking the function after the button element

```html
<input type="button" class="button-class" onclick="fn(this)" value="button" id="btn">
<script>
  function fn(obj){
     console.log(obj)
  }
  fn(document.getElementById("btn"));
</script>
```

Comment: this is a bad solution, you are running your function whe the document loads, not the ``input`` tag. What if append the button via js. This will not work

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO In a comment the questioner has clarified that it's being creating using HTML, not JS.

Answer (score 1):

Just write the function name in onclick property instead of `function(this)` like the following..

```
<script>
    function myFunc(e){
        //do something
    }
</script>
<input type="button" class="button-class" onclick="myFunc(this)">
```

Comment: I do not want the action to be performed on button click. I want the action to be performed as soon as the button is created.

Answer (score 1):

@Bartman pointed out how the `.ready()` funtion handled it as a document.ready.

So i came up with a small solution to run the waanted funtion once the input button is created. Hotfix but cant imagine another solution

I hope this helps. If not please add a comment so i can edit the answer.

```js
function clickFunc(e) {
  alert("click event");
}

function loadFunc() {
  alert("load event");
}

$("#button").click(function() {
  $("div").append("<input id=\"but\" type=\"button\" class=\"button-class\" onclick=\"clickFunc(this)\">");
  $("body").append("<script>loadFunc();<\/script>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="button" type="button">
<div></div>
```

Comment: There's no `ready` event for buttons, this is treated the same as `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Barmar mmmmm. Didnt know that

Comment: It's in the documentation you linked to: **This is because the selection has no bearing on the behavior of the .ready() method, which is inefficient and can lead to incorrect assumptions about the method's behavior.**

Comment: @Barmar you are 100% correct. im working in another solution

Comment: @Barmar the best solution i can find, is to add the code after the append

Comment: He's not using append to create the button.